# Install Mountain Lion to another drive without rebooting

Tags: macos, install

I'm wondering if its possible to install Mountain Lion to an external drive (connected via esata) without rebooting from the host system?

I came across [this hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100122081044636) suggesting that it was possible to do with Snow Leopard, but this method doesnt work with ML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but once you install a clean Mountain Lion system, you can image it to a DMG file and the clone it to your heart's content without rebooting the system doing the copying.